# Confused with the char array when scanf

Tags: c, memory, char, scanf

I am confused with one tiny program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 10

int main()
{
    char str1[LEN] = "\0";
    char str2[LEN] = "\0";

    scanf("%s", str1);
    scanf("%s", str2);

    printf("%s\n", str1);
    printf("%s\n", str2);

    return 0;
}
```

If my input are:

> mangobatao
>   mangobatao123456

Why should the output be:

> 123456
>   mangobatao123456

And not:

> mangobatao
>   mangobatao123456

How has the `char` array has been allocated in the memory?

Comment: `scanf("%s", str)` is inherently unsafe, unless you have complete control over what will appear on stdin.  However big `str` is, the user can type more characters than will fit into it, causing undefined behavior.  (Undefined behavior will crash your program *only* if you're lucky.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291348/why-is-scanf-not-working-as-expected-when-writing-to-a-string-literal

Answer (score 6):

Well, a 10 character `char` array won't fit `"mangobatao"`, since it has 10 characters - there's no room for the null terminator.  That means you've caused undefined behaviour, so anything could happen.

In this case, it looks like your compiler has laid out `str2` before `str1` in memory, so when you call `scanf` to fill `str2`, the longer string overwrites the beginning of `str1`.  That's why you see the end of what you think should be in `str2` when trying to print `str1`. Your example will work fine if you use a length of 100.

Answer (score 0):

I think your compiler has allocated space for str2[10] just 10 characters before the str1 pointer.

Now, when you scanf a string of length 16 at str2, the string terminator '\0' is appended at str2 + 17th position, which is infact str1 + 7.

Now when you call printf at str1, the characters read are actually str2 + 11, str2 + 12,..., str2 + 16 until the null terminator is encountered at str2 + 17 (or str1 + 7).
The printf at str2 must be obvious.