# Why is scanf not working as expected when writing to a string literal?

Tags: c, scanf

```
include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    //char b[10];
    char *a="goodone";
    //a=b;

    scanf("%s",a);//this scanf fails and thow segmentation fault.
    printf("%s",a);

}
```

Why is this not working? I tried a lot with this scanf but, when I reserve memory for my  variable a*(by assigning a=b (commented)) it works fine. Otherwise it doesn't.
I believe that char *a will allocate some memory for its string,("goodone")and return that memory location to its value. And printf working fine with this belief why scanf not?
please save me from this....

Comment: I strongly recommend to read the [C FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html) for this question.

Comment: This is definitely a good read: [What is the difference between char a\[\] = “string”; and char *p = “string”;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are instructing `scanf` to write the data that it reads into the memory allocated for the `const char*` value, i.e. into read-only memory.

If you would like to make your string constant writable, change

```
char *a="goodone";
```

to

```
char a[]="goodone";
```

Note that this is not safe either: it may crash when the user enters more than seven characters. Add a limit to your format specifier in order to address that issue:

```
scanf("%7s",a);
```

P.S. The commented out `a=b` works fine because it is not modifying the string constant; rather, it modifies a *pointer* to character constant, which *is* allowed.

Comment: To emphasize the point, *never* use `scanf()` with a bare `%s` format.  No matter how big a buffer you provide, you cannot prevent the user from entering enough characters to overflow it.  It's as unsafe as `gets()` (which also should never be used).

Comment: @KeithThompson gets() is no longer standard C, since C11.

Comment: @Lundin: Right -- but most or all implementations still provide it (perhaps with a warning), and sadly there are still plenty of books and tutorials that use it.

Answer (score 2):

`char *a` is just a pointer to a `char`. When you assign `"goodone"` to it, it points to that string literal (which is read-only), and `scanf` tries to overwrite that string in memory which causes the crash.

If you assign `b` to it, then you have `a` pointing to a writeable memory area of 10 `char`s (i.e., a string of maximum length 9 + the terminating NUL). So it works as long as `scanf` is not storing anything longer than that in there.

Likewise you could make `a` an array instead of a pointer (i.e., `char a[] = "goodone";`). Again you need to watch out not to store anything longer in there.