# Casting const char* to char* crashes

Tags: c++, casting, string-literals

When I'm trying to cast `const char*` to `char*` it crashes:

```
int myfunc(const char*);
const char * str = "test";
myfunc( (char*)str ) // crash
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Most likely your function modify's the string literal causing Undefined Behavior. The string literal "test" should not be modified. If you do so all bets are off.

Comment: It `myfunc` modifying its argument?

Comment: Don't cast. The function takes `const char*` anyway.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834067/difference-between-char-and-const-char)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char a\[\] = "string"; and char \*p = "string";](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Attempting to modify a *string literal* is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If we look at the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `2.14.5` *String literals* paragraph *12* says:

> Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation defined. The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.

Crashing is one of many possible results of *undefined behavior* it is also possible to have a program that appears to work properly.

Alternatively you can create a *automatic* array as follows:

```
char str[] = "test" ;
```

which will have a copy of the *string literal* which you can then modify.

**Original**

If `myfunc` is modifying a string literal then you have undefined behavior which can easily lead to your program crashing.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is undefined behavior.

You're not allowed to change the memory pointed to by `str`. If you need one you can change, declare it this way instead:

```
char str[] = "test";
```

This will create a mutable copy of the string literal `"test"` for you.