# Difference between char* and const char*

Tags: c, pointers, constants

What is the difference between the following two definitions:

```
char* str = "example";
```

and

```
const char* str = "example";
```

From what I've learnt, in the first definition, the `str` is bound to the address location returned by the compiler for the constant literal. And similar is the treatment for the second definition.

Comment: Right [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834067/difference-between-char-and-const-char)

Comment: Oh. Didn't notice this post. Thanks!