# Set i-th of array pointer as variable in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i am wondering is there any way to set i-th or string in pointer array to local variable?

for example

```
char a = "string";
char b = "string2";
char *args[3];
args[0] = a;
args[1] = b;
args[2] = NULL;
```

therefore,

```
agrs = {"string","string2",NULL};
```

thanks!

Comment: This is invalid C, but treating it as pseudocode, `a` *is* "local" (as in, in the same and in fact only scope I see there).

Comment: `char a;`is a character. If you want to put a string in, you must use `char * a;` or `const char * a;`. Take a look on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834067/difference-between-char-and-const-char).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , you can do that but not with what you have right now . `a` and `b` has to be declared correctly-

```
char *a = "string";                //string literal (constant)
char *b = "string2";               // or write as char b[] = "string2"; 
char *args[3];
args[0] = a;
args[1] = b;
args[2] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can of course index by variable, if that's what you're after:

```
char *a = "string", *b = "string2";
size_t index = 0;
char *args[3];

args[index++] = a;
args[index++] = b;
args[index++] = NULL;
```

I corrected the declarations of `a` and `b` to make them into pointers.