# char* const and editing pointed location using strcpy function in c programming

Tags: c, pointers, char, constants

I'm trying editing the content of location pointed by `char* const`, but this doesn't work.

I'm trying to implement this question answer
[What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Exactly this part:

```
char* const
```

is an immutable pointer (it cannot point to any other location) but the contents of location at which it points is mutable.

I know about literal string which is immutable, but here I'm using `const` so may this be different.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char* const address="mutable content";
  strcpy(&address,"succeed");
  printf("%s\n",address);
  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: You try to copy the string literal `"succeed"` to the address where your pointer `address` is. So you change the value of the pointer (which is UB because the pointer is const), not the value where the pointer points to.

Comment: "mutable content" is not mutable content even though you wrote that it is.

Comment: So, How to change the  content value ?

Comment: See: [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char *s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Comment: I'm trying to implement this question answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834067/difference-between-char-and-const-char

Comment: this answer exactly :
char* const
is an immutable pointer (it cannot point to any other location) but the contents of location at which it points are mutable.

Comment: @YasserMohamed A char* *can* point at immutable content, such as a string literal, although it's discouraged.

Comment: What makes you think just because **you guarantee** to the compiler you will not change **the pointer** does change anything for **the object it points to**?

Comment: I want to understand the question I did mention its link before. so did try this code.
I know about literal string and char pointer, but thought may const word make it different. wish someone kindly  make it clear

Comment: You should call `strcpy(address, "succeed");`, without the ampersand. The ampersand is the "address-of" operator, which returns a pointer to the operand. `strcpy` takes a pointer to a char, but when you use the ampersand you're passing in a pointer to a pointer to a char.