# difference between char and const char

Tags: c++

```
 # include <iostream>
# include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=10;
    int b=20;
    char op[10];
    const char p='+';
    cout<<"enter the operation"<<endl;
    cin>>op;
    if(!strcmp(op,p)==0)
{
        cout<<a+b;
}
    return 0;
}
```

compilation result

12  17  C:\Users\DELL\Documents\cac.cpp [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

I am a beginner. Please tell me what mistake have I done.

Comment: compare `op[0]==p` you'll compare chars it will work.

Comment: as a beginner you should probably... 1) completely forget about `using namespace std;` 2) use `std::string` instead of `char[]` 3) read a book about some basics (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list))

Comment: thank you. but can you tell why do we use op[0]?

Comment: strcmp takes two pointers to character string, it doesn't take a single char as a parameter. here it is not problem of const.

Comment: Read the error message more carefully. The issue isn't `char` vs. `const char`; it's `char` vs. `const char*` -- the `*` is important.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between char\* and const char\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834067/difference-between-char-and-const-char)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't about the difference between `char` and `const char`, but between `char []` and `char`.

`strcmp` expects two character arrays.

`op` is an array of (10) characters.  Good:  that's what `strcmp` expects.

`p` is a single character.  Not good:  `strcmp` needs a char array, and `p` isn't any kind of array, but a single character.

You can change `p` from a single char '+' to a char array "+", or compare only the 0th character of `op`, as suggested in a comment above.

Answer (score 0):

there is no version of strcmp that takes a single character as a parameter but instead it takes two string and compares them.

if you  want to compare a single char variable with a string you can compare it with the first element of string or with any other element:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{

    char op[10]  = "Hi";
    const char p = '+';

   // if( strcmp( op, p) ) // error cannot covert parameter 2 from char to const char*
   //    cout << "op and p are identic" << std::endl;
   // else
   //    std::cout << "op and b are not identic" << std::endl;

    if(op[0] == p)
        std::cout << "op[0] and p are identic" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "op[0] and p are not identic" << std::endl;

    const char* const pStr  = "Bye"; //constant pointer to constant character string: pStr cannot change neither the address nor the value in address
    const char* const pStr2 = "bye"; // the same as above

    // pStr++; //error
    // pStr[0]++; // error 


    if( !strcmp( pStr, pStr2) )
        std::cout << "pStr and pStr2 are identic" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "pStr and pStr2 are Not identic" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `char*` to a string constant is a bit dangerous. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fb7b70d30188233), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20944784)

Comment: @flatmouse I know it's so dangerous. my example's focus is only on strcmp. thanx

Comment: thanx guys. But what really is the difference between char, char*, const char, const char*