# how to pass a parameter to char*?

Tags: c++, string

As in the code below, I can't pass this parameter, how do I fix it?

> E0167 The "const char *" type argument is incompatible with the "char *" type parameter

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int PrintString(char* s)
{
    cout << s << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    PrintString("TESTEEEE");
    return 0;
}
```

I've already tried `PrintString(L"TESTEEEE");`

I've also tried setting the **Project -> Properties -> General -> Character Set** option to use Multi-Byte Character Set.

[image: error image]

Comment: As it says, "TESTSEEE" is a const char *. Change `int PrintString(char* s)` to `int PrintString(const char* s)`.

Comment: ***I've already tried PrintString(L"TESTEEEE");*** For wide character literals you want `int PrintString(const wchar_t* s)`

Comment: Either change the function proto, or const_cast the argument to char *. Remember that modifying literals is UB.

Comment: why can't you edit the function to make its first parameter `const wchar_t* s`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between char\* and const char\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834067/difference-between-char-and-const-char)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This literal `"TESTEEEE"` is of type `char const[9]`. When used as an argument to a function, it can decay to `char const*` but not to `char*`.  Hence to use your function, you have to make the parameter fit to your argument or the opposite as follows

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int PrintString(const char* s)
{
    cout << s << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    PrintString("TESTEEEE");

    return 0;
}
```

[live](https://onlinegdb.com/rkNv6LtpL)

OR

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int PrintString( char* s)
{
    cout << s << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char myArr[] = "TESTEEEE";
    PrintString(myArr);

    return 0;
}
```

[live](https://onlinegdb.com/B1mg0LKpI)

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect constness, it should be:

```
void PrintString(const char* s)
```

Comment: Supplemental background information: [String Literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) A literal isn't necessarily stored in writable memory, so to prevent accidentally writing to one, they are marked `const`.