# How do I store a pointer into my 2d array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am suppose to store the pointer to a command into a 2d array. Below is a little bit of code that I am using, but I dont know how to get the desired result.

```
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024
#define MAX_COMMANDS 10
char *commandHistory[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1];


char *token;
token = strtok(line, LSH_TOK_DELIM);
printf("%s\n", token); //prints out the command I want to store the pointer to
commandHistory[i++][0] = token; //what do I do here?
```

Comment: Why do you split line ? just do  `commandHistory[i++] = strdup(line);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate a copy of the string and store that.  The simplest way to do that is like this:

```
commandHistory[i++][0] = strdup(token);
```

When your program is finished with these, you should `free` each one that is allocated using `strdup`.

Comment: Lets say commandHistory[0][0] = ls. I have another token thats a string that I need to add onto commandHistory[0][0]. How would I do this?

Comment: That would be [a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279718/append-char-to-string-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

You also need not to set second dimension. Declare it like this.

```
char *commandHistory[MAX_COMMANDS]={};
```

This is an array of pointers. You can enforce the `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` of the string read from input source and as others mentioned store the newly allocated string in the location like:

```
commandHistory[i++]= strdup(token);
```

If you want to go with 2 dimensional array then you need to copy the token into the array like:

```
char commandHistory[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1] ={};
strcpy_s(commandHistory[i++], MAX_LINE_LENGTH+1, token);
```