# C - String errors

Tags: c, string

I have a little problem with the `strcat` function in C. All I want is, take a string (`org_surname`), check that the character selected is a consonant and add it to another string(`coded_surname`).

```
int lenght = strlen(org_surname); int i = 0; int count = 0;

while(i<lenght && count < 3){
    if (org_surname[i] != 'a' && org_surname[i] != 'e' && org_surname[i] != 'i' && org_surname[i] != 'i' && org_surname[i] != 'u'){
        strcat(coded_surname,org_surname[i]);
        count++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Errors is always the same.

```
 "passing argoment 2 of strcat makes a from integer without a cast.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The prototype of `strcat()` expects the second parameter to be `const char *` type but what you pass is `char` so there is an error.

You can check [How to append a character to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279718/append-char-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

> Errors is always the same. "passing argoment 2 of strcat makes a from integer without a cast.

That's because you are passing `org_surname[i]` to `strcat`. The second argument to `strcat` needs to be a string, a `char const*`, not a `char`.

You can use:

```
len = strlen(coded_surname);
coded_surname[len] = org_surname[i];
coded_surname[len+1] = '\0';
```