# strcat returning wrong character

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am using strcat to build a string. It works except for when I want to append characters that represent numbers from an array. The line that uses:

```
strcat(JsonDataStr, numsToSend[i]);
```

for example appends the character 'c' instead of '1'. If I manually put the character in using double quotes it works, but i want to have a one dimensional array with characters only.

```
char JsonDataStr[20];

void buildJsonString(){

    int offset;
    char strtStr[] = "[{\""  ;
    char numStr[4];
    char numsToSend[4] = {'1', '2','3','4'};

    offset = sizeof(strtStr);

    strcat(JsonDataStr, strtStr);

    for(i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++){
           strcat(JsonDataStr, JsonDataName);
           ByteToStr(i, numStr);
           strcat(JsonDataStr, numsToSend[i]);
           strcat(JsonDataStr, "\":\"");
    }
    strcat(JsonDataStr, "\"}]");
}
```

Any idea why this is happening.

Comment: `strcat` expects _strings_. You give it a char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `strcat` like this. It appends strings to strings, not single chars to strings. A quick fix would be to have `numsToSend` as an array of char pointers instead:

```
char *numsToSend[4] = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
```

Other than that you could write a function that appends chars to strings, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10279911/10411602) answer for an example.

Comment: Thank you kindly. That works a treat now. That other example is good to.