# Using char/string pointers in C gives weird output

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, char

I'm trying to generate the following output:

```
0.1

0.12

0.123

0.1234

...

0.123456789
```

My code uses string/char arrays and some pointer data types that I'm not familiar with.

Code was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279718/append-char-to-string-in-c) to help get started, but I get the following output of gibberish.

[CMD Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBE3m.png)

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "0.";
    char digit = '0';

    size_t len = strlen(str);

    int i = 1;


    while(i<10)
    {
        printf("i: %d\n",i);
    
        char *temp = malloc(len + 1 + 1);
    
        len = strlen(temp);
    
        digit = i + '0';
    
        temp[len] = digit;
    
        char string[len];
    
        strcpy(string,temp);
    
        free(temp);
    
        printf("%s\n\n",string);
    
        i = i +1;
    }
}
```

What needs to be modified to get the data types to work correctly together?

Comment: `temp` points to the `malloc` allocated memory but no string is stored in it, so `strlen(temp)` will result in some random value...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @ismick mentioned, `temp` points to unintialized memory and so can contain anything. A safer bet, especially for `0`-terminated strings like C, is to use `calloc`.

It's also quite a bit simpler to use `sprintf` rather than `strcpy`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "0.";

    size_t len = 2;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\n", i);                                                                            
        len = len + 2;

        char *temp = calloc(len, sizeof(char));
        sprintf(temp, "%s%d", str, i); 
        if (i > 1) free(str); // string literal when i=1
        str = temp;
        printf("%s\n\n", str);
    }
    free(str);
}
```

A few new  things here: `for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)` or `for(int i = 1; i < 10; i = i+1)` are a handy shortcut for the common construction

```
int i = 1;

while (i < 10) {
  ....
  i = i + 1;
}
```

We use `calloc` to get a pointer to a block of memory that's initialized with `0`; the second `sizeof(char)` parameter tells us to get a block that fits `len`-many `char`s.

We use `sprintf(temp, "%s%d", str, i);` to ease copying the previous value of `str` into this new block of memory plus the next digit, e.g. `0.` ~~> `0.1` or `0.12` ~~> `0.123`.

Finally, we set `str = temp;` to point `str` to the start of `temp`, so we don't lose the copied/concatenated string we just made using `sprintf`.

**edit:** add comments about code
**edit 2:** fixed the double `free` pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Sadly, I forgot to `free(temp)` at the last line of the for loop, and then `free(str)` at the end of main!

Comment: this crashes, you free the str twice.

Comment: you also use `str` when it still points to the free'd `temp`, therefore it produces funny output.

Comment: You're right! I compiled it first without any free, and it produces the intended output. Then I carelessly tried to fix it on my phone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by @isrnick, the problem is that you allocate memory but don't initialize it before calling `strlen`.

It is in general not a good idea to repeatedly alloc/free memory as it fragments the heap. It is better to allocate once in the beginning, reuse the memory and free it in the end.

A better and neater solution would be to keep it on the *stack*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[64] = "0.";

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        str[1 + i] = '0' + i;
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.1
0.12
0.123
0.1234
0.12345
0.123456
0.1234567
0.12345678
0.123456789
```

Comment: Do you think it would be better to keep it on the stack if you wanted the code to handle strings up to 100+ digits?

Comment: For small array lengths (<= 512)  I would keep it on the stack, it's hard to give a general answer because it depends on your system and the application. It is in general bad to *repeatedly* alloc/free small amounts of memory. It fragments the memory and it's also harder to keep track of it (imagine a larger system with multiple files). It's better to allocate a single junk, reuse it and free it at the end.