# casting error arising upon appending a string to another one

Tags: c, char, c-strings, string-literals

I am trying to append a certain string (characters array) to another one as suggested here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279718/append-char-to-string-in-c#:~:text=To%20append%20a%20char%20to%20a%20string%20in,because%20the%20given%20literal%20string%20cannot%20be%20modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279718/append-char-to-string-in-c#:%7E:text=To%20append%20a%20char%20to%20a%20string%20in,because%20the%20given%20literal%20string%20cannot%20be%20modified)

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

char *mystring="Life";
int length_string=strlen(mystring);

char *string_continuation=" is life";
int length_continuation=strlen(string_continuation);

char *new_word=malloc(length_string+length_continuation+1);
strcpy(new_word,mystring);

for (int i=0; i<length_string; i++){
    
    
new_word[length_string+i]=string_continuation[i];

}
new_word[length_continuation+length_string]="\0";

printf("The final word is %s", new_word);
free (new_word);

return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting the typical error:

```
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

which refers to line:

```
 new_word[length_continuation+length_string]="\0";
```

Does anyone know why such error arises? Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this assignment statement

```
new_word[length_continuation+length_string]="\0";
```

the right operand of the assignment is string literal `"\0"` that has the type `char[2]` and is implicitly converted in the expression to the type `char *`.

On the other hand, the left operand has the type `char`. So the compiler issues the error.

You need to write

```
new_word[length_continuation+length_string]='\0';
```

using integer character constant `'\0'`.

Pay attention that there is a typo in the for loop. Instead of

```
for (int i=0; i<length_string; i++){
```

there must be

```
for (int i=0; i<length_continuation; i++){
```

Also instead of the for loop you could just use the standard C function `strcat` as for example

```
strcat( new_word, string_continuation );
```

Comment: @4386427 Thanks. I forgot where there is left and where there is right.:)