# If Strings are immutable,why does the following code run on turbo c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

```
char c[]="opop";
c[2]='k';
```

But it should give a bus error,why does it work?

Comment: Even if you were actually modifying a string literal (which you aren't), a premise of "Why does invoking undefined behavior work here?" is flawed.  Undefined behavior means that *anything* could happen (including some definition of "working").

Comment: I thought the title was saying `std::string` is immutable, which, of course, it's not.

Answer (score 7):

What you have is an array, not an string literal. It is perfectly valid code.

```
char *c="opop";
c[2]='k';
```

Would cause an Undefined Behavior and most likely a crash.

Good Read:
[What is the difference between char a[] = "string"; and char *p = "string";](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string/9631091#9631091)

Comment: I'd like to add a comment that Turbo C++ is old, and that string literals (defined by char * = "opop") used to be writeable for backwards compatibility. GCC still has a -wwriteable-strings (I believe) flag to allow this.

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave: The link in the answer to one of my old answer explains this much more in detail with standardese quotes.

Comment: I haven't used C++ for 8 years. Is this immutability a "new" feature of the language? Also, I always thought char c[] and char* c were synonyms?

Comment: @Eduardo read the link he posted. basically, char[] and char pointer are not the same data type; char[] can decay into char pointer, but it is not. short answer, char[] declares an array and initializes it, char pointer declares a pointer and points it to a string literal.

Comment: @Eduardo: An array and a pointer were never & still are not same in C/C++. It is one of the most widely spread misconception that they are synonymous, they are not! You should check out the link in the answer for a detailed description.

Comment: Very interesting link. I am trying to re-learn C++ these days and it is a very useful point to keep in mind.

Comment: @VJovic: Yes, in C++11, Not in C++03, C++03(§4.2/2) merely deprecates use of string literal without the `const` keyword.

Comment: @VJovic: The linked answer is mine and it aptly explains the semantics involved in greater detail.So I dont think that really justify's an downvote.Ofcourse, You don't need to justify any downvotes but Since that is the reasoning you present for the downvote its not really justified.

Comment: I didn't downvote (I could only prove by downvoting if you like). turbo c++ is an ancient compiler, so c++11 are not there (not sure if even c++03 are there).