# difference between char *myString and myString[]

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)
>   [What is the difference between char a[] = “string”; and char *p = “string”;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

I want to know what is difference between below two string declaration in C language

```
char *myString = "This is a C character string";
```

and

```
char myString[] = "This is a C character array";
```

I know that first one is pointer and second is array but i couldn't get the difference.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1335786/1330481

Comment: Duplicate question a hundred times over, at least.  Why don't people just search?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Binyamin Sharet's answer, in the first case you can change the `myString` pointer, but in the second case you can't. So, this code will compile and run and print "ello":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *myString = "Hello\n";

    myString++;

    printf("%s", myString);
}
```

But this code won't compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char myString[] = "Hello\n";

    myString++;

    printf("%s", myString);
}
```