# Does a pointer to a char overwrite memory when used to point to a string?

Tags: c++, string

```
char str[]="Hello";
```

this allocates 6 bytes for the string , but if i write

```
char *str = "Hello";
```

will this overwrite data because it was just meant to store 1 char? So what i'm asking is that when i declare a string, but not initialize it (char str[12]; ) , do 12 bytes get reserved here or when i initialize it? And if they do get initialized here, so that means that in:

```
char *str;
```

only 1 byte gets reserved, but when i make it point to a string, doesn't that overwrite data beyond it's bounds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char a\[\] = "string"; and char *p = "string";](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

Comment: As with your previous question, the conversion in the expression `char *str = "Hello";` is still incorrect (and you should be warned by the compiler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *str;
```

does not reserve any data for content.  It is a pointer, sized to hold a memory address.

```
char *str = "Hello";
```

6 bytes for `{ 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 }` already has been stored somewhere by the compiler.  Now you are making a variable holding its address (pointing to it).  The string content is not copied.

Answer (score 0):

```
char str[]="Hello";
```

You got that right, its an array of 6 `char`s

```
char *str = "Hello";
```

That's a pointer to a string literal. Somewhere there is an array of 6 `char`s and your variable `str` is just pointing to it.

```
char *str;
```

This does not reserve anything, its a pointer pointing to an indeterminated place. When you make it point to a string, then it points to an array of `char`s that lives somewhere else, there is no copy involved.

Comment: <pedant>Unless the optimizer eliminates the local pointer variable, space will be reserved for it, enough space to hold a memory address</pedant>