# Pointers and Strings causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between char a[] = “string”; and char *p = “string”;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

```
char *str = "Hello";
printf("%c",++*str);
```

This gives segmentation fault on linux with gcc.
The moment the first statement is changes to as

```
char str[10] = "Hello";
```

It works. What may be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

It is undefined behaviour to attempt to modify a string literal.

The compiler is free to place it in read-only memory (as it probably does in your case). Attempting to modify read-only memory is what's probably triggering the segfault.

Answer (score -1):

This statement `char *str = "Hello";` stores the string "Hello" in RO-section and assigns the address of the area of RO-section(in which "Hello"is stored) to str. The data stored in RO-section cannot be modified thus you are getting a segfault.

```
char str[10] = "Hello";
```

is also wrong. You should instead write

```
char str[10];
strncpy(str,"Hello",sizeof(str));
```

Comment: I cannot see how `char str[10] = "Hello";` is wrong. INO it is just perfext for this case. Well I would probably use `char str[] = "Hello";` but that doesn't make the given code wrong.

Comment: I think its a bad idea to copy string this way. I am fine with char str[]="Hello" which lets compiler decide the size. However, the above practice char str[10]="Hello" can lead to segfault when say, a  programmer changes/modifies the string. 
Lets say you have a code
#define STR "Hello"
and you are using char str[10] = STR;
When, the programmer changes the macro STR to "HELLOWORLD!!!!" he mayget segfault.

Comment: `char str[10] = STR;` would copy the `#define`d `STR` into the `.data` segment, where it is perfectly modifiable. It won't definitely modify anything else.

Comment: I was talking about the string copy/initialization for #defined case(Not implying printf("%c",++*str); modification).

Comment: Oh, yes! Now I got it. Yes, in this case you are right. Sorry for the confusion. In this case, the string isn't 0-terminated any longer, which makes using it dangerous.

Comment: But be aware that the `strncpy()` solution is not as easy as it seems, as ["If there is no null byte in the first n bytes of the array pointed to by s2, the result is not null-terminated."](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncpy.html) Instead, `strncpy(str,"Hello",sizeof(str)-1); str[sizeof(str)-1]='\0';` would be the way to go.