# Initializing a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between char *str=“STRING” and char str[] = “STRING”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862842/difference-between-char-str-string-and-char-str-string)

I wrote the following code:

```
int main()
{
    char *str = "hello";
    str[0] = 'H';
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

This gives me a segmentation fault, I cant understand why.

`str` is `pointer to char` not `const char`. Even if that's the case shouldn't it give a compile error like the following program:

```
int main()
{
    const char *str = "hello";
    str[0] = 'H';
    printf("%s\n", str);    
}
```

It gives an error: `assignment of read-only location *str`.

**EDIT**

If my code places the pointer to a read only location, shouldn't I get a compilation error?

Comment: Please use the search feature. If you searched you would find hundreds of the exact same question.

Comment: @Marlon please paste a link of a duplicate question on stackoverflow

Comment: The pointer is not read only. It just points to where your string is stored in memory. There is a subtle difference between the ways you can declare your string that changes how it's stored.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098074/pointers-and-strings-causing-segmentation-fault, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958222/unknown-segmentation-fault, ................... "char segmentation fault" "string segmentation fault", etc.

Comment: "If my code places the pointer to a read only location, shouldn't I get a compilation error." Why? There is nothing syntactically incorrect with the code.

Comment: "If my code places the pointer to a read only location, shouldn't I get a compilation error." what you do is a perfectly valid assignment. What the compiler does not know is that in a standard system constant strings are placed in read-only memory. On embedded systems this may be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assign a pointer to a constant string (which comes as a part of your text and is thus not writable memory).

Fix with `char str[] = "hello";` this will create a r/w copy of the constant string on your stack.

What you do is a perfectly valid pointer assignment. What the compiler does not know is that in a standard system constant strings are placed in read-only memory. On embedded (or other weird) systems this may be different.

Depending on your system you could come with an `mprotect` and change the VM flags on your pointer destination to writable. So the compiler allows for this code, your OS does not though.

Comment: The string literal is not `const` nor constant. It is standard array of `char` just big enough to hold all the characters plus the terminator which is not writeable under penalty of Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize a `char *` using a literal string, then you shouldn't try to modify it's contents: the variable is pointing to memory that doesn't belong to you.

You *can* use:

```
char str[] = "hello";
str[0] = 'H';
```

With this code you've declared an array which is initialized with a copy of the literal string's contents, and now you can modify the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behavior in runtime. You are attempting to write to a literal string, which is not allowed. Such writes may trigger an error or have undefined behavior. Your specific C compiler has `str` point to read-only memory, and attempting to write to that memory leads to a segmentation fault. Even though it's not `const`, the write is still not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *str = "hello";
```

When you declare `str` as above, it is not guaranteed which part of memory it will be stored. str might be read-only depending on implementation. So trying to change it will cause segmentation fault.

In order to avoid segmentation faullt, declare `str` as an array of characters instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *str = "hello";
```

here the string hello is a literal.
string literals are always stored in read only memory.
this is the reason you are getting a segmentation fault when you are trying to change the value at read only memory.

Comment: String literals are stored wherever the implementation wants them to be stored which is not necessarily read only.

Comment: In the overwhelming majority of cases they are stored in read-only memory.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring str as char* reserves memory for the pointer, but not for the string.
The compiler can put the memory for "hello" anywhere he likes.
You have no guarantee that str[i] is writable, so that's why in some compilers this results in a seg fault.

If you want to make sure that the string is in writable memory, then you have to allocate memory using alloc() or you can use

```
char str[] = "hello";
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get why compiler cant put the memory for "hello" wherever he likes