# char ch[]="some string";

Tags: c, string

I am having a conceptual doubt.

```
char ch[20]="some string";
```

I wanted to know how ch is being stored i.e. whether 20 bytes are allocated or just the length of the string assigned to it? Can we access something like ch[18] here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **I wanted to know how `ch` is being stored i.e. whether `20` bytes are allocated or just the length of the string assigned to it?**

It creates an array by name `ch` which is `20` characters long and initalizes it with "some string".
Yes, the array is 20 bytes in size.

> **Can we access something like ch[18] here?**

Yes We can. And even modify the contents.

**Good Read:**

[What is the difference between char a[] = “string”; and char *p = “string”;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string/9631091#9631091)

---

To answer Q in comment:

```
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+      +----+----+
  ch:| s | o | m | e |   | s |  t |  r |  i |  n |  g | \0 |    |      | b  | \0 |
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+      +----+----+
       0   1   2   3   4   5   6    7    8     9   10   11   12  ......  18   19
```

When you do,

```
 ch[18]='b';
```

The modification has happend only that you cannot see it.
`printf` determines the end of string by detecting `\0`. The `\0` was placed at the end of the string when you initialized it.The rule in C/C++ while declaring an array  whenever initializers are given, any uninitialized elements are automatically set to 0. As you see in above the diagram depiction the modified character is placed after what `printf` thinks is end of string and hence you cannot see it in output of `printf`.

If you output the string each character by a for-loop by iterating over it, You can see your modification.

Comment: I tried this but not getting the edited ch string.
char ch[20]="some string";
        ch[18]='b';
        printf(ch);

Comment: If the string is shorter than the array, it is padded with 0 bytes. printf prints up to the first 0 byte it finds, which is ch[11]. Changing ch[18] works, but isn't seen with printf.

Comment: @MasterWayne: Modified the answer to address your Q in comment.Hope that helpes.

Answer (score 3):

> whether 20 bytes are allocated

Yes, 20 bytes are allocated since you told it to do so. It's just that the first 12 bytes of the array will be **initialized** using your string and its trailing NUL, the other bytes are padded with zeros. However, you can still access (read and write) all the 20 bytes of the array, i. e. from `ch[0]` to `ch[19]`.

If you had written

```
char ch[] = "some string";
```

then `ch` would have been created as a 12-element array:

```
{ 's', 'o', m', 'e', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 0 }
```

and only then would it have been erroneous to attempt to read or write past the bounds of the array, i . e. `ch[12]` and higher indices would have invoked undefined behavior.

If you write

```
char *ch = "some string";
```

that's really bad and if you need a string literal as a char pointer, you should really write

```
const char *ch = "some string";
```

In this case, the `ch` pointer points to a 12-byte long string, of which the characters are constant, so they're read-only - attempting to **modify** them (in addition to reading out of the bounds) is, again, undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

20 bytes are allocated to `ch` since you declared it to use 20 bytes. yes you Can access ch[18].

The problem with

```
char ch[20] = "some string";
ch[18] = 'b';
printf("%s",ch);
```

is that the literal "some string" is stored including its `NULL` terminator, so when you print it the string only prints till the first null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access ch[18], you overallocated the array and the bytes after your constant  string will still be there, full of uninitialized data.  Look at the memory location.

Answer (score 1):

```
`how ch is being stored`   and   `whether 20 bytes are allocated`
```

20 bytes are allocated actually, and the memory addresses allocated are constant.
"ch" here is a pointer to the first byte(or char) of the memory allocated. And "ch+1" points the second byte of the memory allocated.

```
Can we access something like ch[18] here?
```

If the length of string is shorter than the memory size you requested(20 in this case), you still get the requested size, and the values in other bytes are not certain(may be 0 or not, but in vc6, it is often intialized as 0). ch[18] can be accessed, but the value may be unknown. So you may have to take the efforts to initialize them to 0 by yourself, if you want to access them.

Comment: I tried this but not getting the edited ch string. char ch[20]="some string"; ch[18]='b'; printf(ch); What could be the problem?

Comment: "printf()" will stop at '\0', what you want may be achieved by initializing other bytes as ' '(white-space) and  '\0' as last byte.