# Using sizeof() on a void pointer pointing to a buffer (string " ") in C++ in order to get the size in BYTES?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, sizeof, void-pointers

```
void * ptr0 = (void*)"Buffer_1";
int size0 = sizeof(ptr0);
// WILL THIS RETURN THE NUMBER OF BYTES OCCUPIED BY THE MEMORY POINTED BY ptr0?
```

My requirement is
1)  store some data in buffer & create a void* pointer to it which I am doing in 1st line.
2) Later I want to get the size of this buffer in BYTES. The 2nd line will do this job.

Comment: What you are asking is not only not what happens, but it's literally impossible. Consider, for example, if `ptr0` points to two distinct objects that have the same beginning contents (say either a single integer or an array of two integers). How could `sizeof` know which object you wanted the size of?

Comment: Just use std::string or std::vector<char>, you're trying to do things the hard way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sizeof` returns the size required by the type. Since the type you pass to `sizeof` in this case is pointer, it will return size of the pointer.

If you need the size of the data pointed by a pointer you will have to remember it by storing it explicitly.

Comment: I would add that if you need to see the size of string, instead of a pointer use an array i.e. char arr[] = "string"; then sizeof(arr) would return the length of string

Comment: @fayyazkl: I would rather add: [What is the difference between char a\[\] = “string”; and char *p = “string”;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string/9631091#9631091)

Answer (score 2):

No this will simply return the size of your pointer in bytes. Using `sizeof` to get the size of an array will only work on arrays declared like this

```
char szArray[10];
```

not on arrays created dynamically

```
char* pArray = new char[10];

sizeof(szArray);  // number of elements * sizeof(char) = 10
sizeof(pArray);   // sizeof the pointer
```

Answer (score 1):

sizeof() works at compile time. so `sizeof(ptr0)` will return 4 or 8 bytes typically. instead use `strlen`? or actually store the no. of bytes held by the `(void *)` in a separate variable.