# Need explanation for C output

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between char a[] = “string”; and char *p = “string”;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

```
int main() {
 char *p="ayqm";
 char c;
 c=++*p;
 printf("%c",c);
 return 0;
}
```

Its output is `a`. See http://codepad.org/cbNOPuWt But I feel that the output should be `b` since `c = ++*p`.
Anybody can explain the reason for the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, it's **undefined behavior**. Anything can happen.

You're attempting to modify a string literal, which is illegal.

If you do, for example

```
char c = *p;
++c;
```

you'll see the correct output.

The actual type of `p` should be `const char*`, in which case you'd get a compiler error.

Comment: Augh! Beat me to it by a second :)

Comment: @habeebperwad you could see it as that, yes. But `++'a'` is also illegal.