# Changing chars while walking a string crashes program

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)
>   [What is the difference between char a[] = “string”; and char *p = “string”;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

Can anyone point out the problem in following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *c = "Hello World!! !!";
    char c2 = 'X';
    while(c)
    {
        if(*c == ' ')
        {
            printf("%s",c);
            *c = c2;
        }
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It crashes  at `*c = c2;` with following error :

```
Thread [1] (Suspended : Signal : EXC_BAD_ACCESS:Could not access memory)    
    main() at mainclass.cpp:64 0x100000d74
```

I used GCC as compiler on MAC OSX and Eclipse as IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `c` points to a string literal. The line `*c = c2` tries to modify the string literal, which is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). One possible manifestation of the undefined behaviour is that string literals are put into read-only memory and you get a [`SIGSEGV`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) or similar.

If you change the code as follows, it should work:

```
char arr[] = "Hello World!! !!";
char* c = arr;
```

Now `c` points into an array. Unlike string literals, it is permissible to modify the contents of an array.

Lastly, your while-loop is incorrectly conditioned on the value a pointer, not the value it points *to*. You're looking for a null-terminator ('\0'). It should look like this:

```
while (*c)
{
    ...
    c++;
}
```

Comment: @NPE Please keep link to "undefined behaviour" wiki page...

Answer (score 2):

When you do: `char *c = "Hello World!! !!";` then ***c*** is a pointer that **points to a memory 
that is in the code part**, so you *can't* change it.

But if you have `char c[] = "Hello World!! !!";` then ***c*** is **an array of chars that are on the stack**, so you *can* change it.

In this case, it is better to do: `char const *c = "Hello World!! !!";` because then, if you try to change the string as you are doing, your program won't crash, it will arise a compiler error and won't run the program, which is much better.