# How do I avoid segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The code is self-explanatory, but it gives me segmentation fault, why? :\

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *c = "Hella";
    *(c+4) = 'o';
    printf("%s\n",c);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to use your compiler warnings or to pay attention to them or to understand them.

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/string-literals-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **How to avoid it?**

Don't modify a string literal!

```
char *c = "Hella";
```

Declares a pointer `c` to a string literal "Hella" stored in implementation defined read only memory.
You are not allowed to modify this literal. An attempt to do so results in **Undefined Behavior**.

You are lucky that your program crashes, an Undefined Behavior does not always result in a crash but may cause your program to behave weirdly in any possible way.

What you need here is an array:

```
char c[] = "Hella";
```

**Good Read:**
[What is the difference between char a[] = ?string?; and char *p = ?string?;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

Answer (score 1):

Put your string into an array allocated onto the stack:

```
char c[] = "Hella";
```

Because as said, string literals are usually read-only.

Answer (score 0):

the way you create `c` it points to a string literal. You can not modify it's contents. If you want to be able to do that use:

```
char c[6] = "Hella";
c[4] = o;
```

Or use a dynamically allocated char array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to overwrite a literal.  Really your code should read:

```
const char *c = "Hella";
```

Which kinda explains what is going on.

To overwrite your own memory:

```
char c[] = "Hella";
```

is safer.

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify strings that are defined in code. Use strdup if you want to modify them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *c = strdup("Hella");
    *(c+4) = 'o';
    printf("%s\n",c);
    free(c);
}
```

Comment: @Geoffrey. It is not correct to edit the sense of a post. You can edit only the form. Language, format etc. You can propose the change in a comment though.

Comment: Yes, the change was correct, but according to rules we should use edit for the form only, not the content! Geoffrey should propose the content change by the means of a comment.

Comment: Huh really sorry for that Gangnus this should never happen again, I'll carry it out. Thanks!