# Using strtok with char array parameter

Tags: c++

I am trying to split a char array with delimiter.

This gives me a runtime error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
int main()
{
    char* largechars = "q=test&use=bingo";
    char* chars_array = strtok(largechars, "&");
    while(chars_array)
    {
        std::cout << chars_array << '\n';
        chars_array = strtok(NULL, "&");
    }
}
```

Demo here http://ideone.com/OpNssn

This program works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
int main()
{
    char largechars[] = "q=test&use=bingo";
    char* chars_array = strtok(largechars, "&");
    while(chars_array)
    {
        std::cout << chars_array << '\n';
        chars_array = strtok(NULL, "&");
    }
}
```

Demo here http://ideone.com/Ye8C8k

What is the issue here?

Comment: Using strtok in C++ should give you a hint that something might be wrong. Also, literals are const char *.

Comment: but both are char array am i correct?

Comment: No, the first version  isn't using an array, but a pointer to a string literal. Literals are constants. And [pointers and arrays are *very* different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string).

Comment: About splitting strings in C++, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c).

Comment: Closing & Read about differences between pointers and arrays.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/ the functions take char pointer as parameter so i thought i could use it.

Comment: @Kathick - You're on the right track, but a pointer to a literal is `const char*` and not what `strtok` expects. The compiler should warn you that the first assignment is a bit fishy.

Comment: Don't use C functions. Don't use cplusplus.com. An *read* before asking questions.

Comment: @Kathick A string literal has type `char const[]` in C++, and in C, it is defined to be immutable despite having a type `char[]`.  And of course, `strtok` is one of those functions which are broken, even in C, and should never be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the contents of string argumnet (in your case `largechars`) is modified and broken into smaller strings (tokens) by this function `strtok`. But in your first sample first argument is  `const char*` So when it tries to modify the content it will result in run time error

Answer (score 0):

`strtok()` modifies  its argument when it parses the string

Your first example supplies a variable that is read-only as argument to the `strtok` and therefore you get the runtime error. In your second example you supply an argument that can be modified.